# SQLi PHP DB connection issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cannot make a connection to my db, I am using an if statement to see if the table contains rows of data; if it does, echo "success".

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
$sql = "SELECT id, Name, Description, Price FROM products_table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

function products() {

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "There are no products avaliable.";
}
else {
    echo "Success!";
}
```

}

I am unsure as to why this isn't working, any help would be appreciated, it's probably something very small and easy to figure out.

I am calling products() on another page called index.php which simply contains html tags, nothing that would bring up errors.

Comment: variable scope: http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You're mixing APIs. You're creating a `mysqli` connection, and then you're trying to call `mysql_num_rows` on it.

Comment: ok thanks @DarwinvonCorax

Comment: Scope is also an issue, as @Federico points out.